# I have php file that won't validate to display the right error message

Tags: php

This wont display the error message in submission, I don't know what is wrong, my code seems alright to me. For some reason, the error code within the span elements fails the display the error message when the text failed. Not even the data echoed out was printed after the submission of the form.

```
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo
            $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
           <label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Enter
              fullname here" name="name">
              <span class="err"><?php echo @$name_err; ?></span>
           </label>
           <label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Enter 
               Email here" name="email">
               <span class="err"><?php echo @$email_err; ?></span>
               </label>
           <label>
               <input type="submit" value="submit">
            </label>
         </form>
      </body>
    </html>

     <?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

        $name = $email = '';
        $name_err = $email_err = '';
        if(!empty($_POST['name'])) {
            $name = $_POST['name'];
       } else {
            $name_err = 'You fullname is required';
       }

        if(!empty($_POST['email'])) {
            $email = $_POST['email'];
       }else {
        $email_err = 'Your email is required';
    }
    }

   echo $name.'<br>';
   echo $email.'<br>';
?>
```

Comment: You don't do anything with $name_err? plus your email validation dumps into this varaible

Comment: I have echoed the err message to be displayed underneath the input field, since the form will be submitted to itself

Comment: because your variables are defined after to print them.

Comment: why on earth would you prefix your vars with an `@`? Don't suppress errors, just fix them

Comment: to supress the errors i gues, but how can i actually get it right now?

Comment: Error messages are intentionally placed there by PHP creators as a mean to help programmers. Suppressing them totally beats the point.

Comment: I know, i should check before rending, but the code should work, but why is it not working?

Comment: Because you print the variable first and you populate it afterwards—probably what the suppressed error message would have told you ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. You should check your errors **before** rendering form. Also you had wrong variable name for $email_err

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

        $name = $email = '';
        $name_err = $email_err = '';
        if(!empty($_POST['name'])) {
            $name = $_POST['name'];
       } else {
            $name_err = 'You fullname is required';
       }

        if(!empty($_POST['email'])) {
            $email = $_POST['email'];
       }else {
        $email_err = 'Your email is required';
    }
    }

   echo $name.'<br>';
   echo $email.'<br>';
?>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo
        $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
       <label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter
          fullname here" name="name">
          <span class="err"><?php echo @$name_err; ?></span>
       </label>
       <label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter 
           Email here" name="email">
           <span class="err"><?php echo @$email_err; ?></span>
           </label>
       <label>
           <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </label>
     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @pedroyanky Please read the answer carefully. You have the HTML first.

Comment: It seems to be thesame a mine

Comment: No, it is not same. My code work, your code will not never work.

Comment: I would think the problem with my approach was the ordering, The php  code came first. but is that supposed to matter?